# Restart sound indicator in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

When the sound crashes, I can restart it with:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

However, that doesn't bring the sound indicator (system tray indicator) back.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with LightDm.

Comment: Not sure what mixer app LightDM uses by default.  When your system tray icon is there and you open the mixer, what is the name of the program (look in the title bar or elsewhere in the app).  This is the program you'll need to restart to get the tray icon back.

Answer (score 1):

Try look at the indicator-sound-gtk2 package, or anything other `indicator-*` package.

You might try to start `/usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service`, and see if the indicator gets back to the panel.

I don't have a Ubuntu at hand, so I cannot testify that for you.

Answer (score 0):

For xfce, try this:

```
pkill notify-osd
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

As a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
pkill notify-osd
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

See also: http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8847

Hopefully it'll give you a clue as to how to fix LightDM.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service and then start it again.

Tangentially, the reason I discovered your question is because I've encountered an issue where restarting pulseaudio leaves the sound tray icon mouse scroll wheel volume control stuck controlling the wrong device. My particular system is on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.